# Python SEM_OPEN Error

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am trying to use Celery running with RabbitMQ and Django. So far i have RabbitMQ 2.7 installed on my server, along with python 2.7 , Django 1.3, celery 2.4.6 and django-celery 2.4.2

i followed the simple instructions here http://django-celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html

and then i tried to start celery by running

```
$ python manage.py celeryd
```

but it gave me this error

```
Unrecoverable error: ImportError('This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives needed will not function, see issue 3770.
```

i did some research and found the bug here http://bugs.python.org/issue3770, and its supposedly fixed, but i guess not for python 2.7.

Also, My OS is CentOS release 4.9 (Final). And i built python from source.

I started the python shell and ran :

```
import multiprocessing
```

with no errors, however i then ran:

```
from multiprocessing import synchronize
```

and i got the error ( above ).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your OS? Did you build python yourself or install from a package manager? Does `import multiprocessing` in a plain python shell work?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i edited the question to include the information you requested.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same problem on CentOS 6 running under OpenVZ. I had to mount `/dev/shm` because it was missing. Add the following to `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs   /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults        0   0
```

And then run `sudo mount /dev/shm` and see if it works. I had my own custom built Python 2.7.3 and this device *needs to be present when building as well*, otherwise Python will not be build with `sem_open` support. Check for the following output when running `./configure`:

```
checking for sem_open... yes
```

Comment: Unfortunately i was using a shared server, so i had no way of mounting it, so i bought a new server running Ubuntu 11.10 and it worked :). Thanks